# WebClient builder Post Call giving bad request error for first time in Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

First post request  giving bad request error for Webclient on first click.
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST

After that every request process succsfully. 
exception i'm getting below

```
* Submitting xyz 
     * @param submitFlowRequest
     */
@Override
public Mono<ApiResponse<SubmitResponse>> submitFlow(SubmitFlowRequest submitFlowRequest,
        Map<String, String> headers) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String uri = propertyConfig.getAggregationService()
            + propertyConfig.getAggregationSubmitCCInfoURL();
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(uri);
    factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> clientHeaders = buildHeaders(headers);
    return webClientBuilder.uriBuilderFactory(factory).build().post()
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(clientHeaders)).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .syncBody(submitFlowRequest).retrieve().bodyToMono(ApiResponse.class)
            .onErrorMap(ConnectException.class,
                    error -> new VzwRuntimeException(ErrorCodeEnum.V404.toString(), Constants.OPP_TC_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                            (Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_TEXT + Constants.AGGREGATION)))
            .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class,
                    error -> new VzwRuntimeException(ErrorCodeEnum.V404.toString(), Constants.OPP_TC_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                            (Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_TEXT + Constants.AGGREGATION)))
            .flatMap(res -> {
                Audit apiAudit = Audit.builder().apiUrl(uri).request(LoggerUtil.asJson(submitFlowRequest))
                        .response(LoggerUtil.asJson(res))
                        .executionTime(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
                        .headers(LoggerUtil.asJson(clientHeaders)).transactionType(res.getData()!=null?mapper.map(res.getData(), SubmitResponse.class).getTransactionType():"").build();
                LoggerUtil.logExternalApiCalls(apiAudit);
                return Mono.just((ApiResponse<SubmitResponse>) res);
            });
}
```

Exception :::

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST http://WKWIN93.global.sangwan.net:9898/payment-ag/v1/creditcard/submitCreditCardInfo
            at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:179)
            Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
        Error has been observed at the following site(s):
            |_ checkpoint ⇢ 400 from POST http://payment-service/payment-ag/v1/creditcard/submitCreditCardInfo [DefaultWebClient]
        Stack trace:
                at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:179)
                at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:209)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
                at com.sgw.common.logging.mdc.MDCContextHelper.onNext(MDCContextHelper.java:30)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100)
                at com.sgw.common.logging.mdc.MDCContextHelper.onComplete(MDCContextHelper.java:46)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHide.java:137)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122)
```

Comment: What is the resolution this issue? Any luck? facing similar problem...

Comment: i have the same problem in windows :(